# What is the difference between "Boruto: Naruto Next Generation" manga and "Boruto: Naruto the Movie"?

Tags: naruto, boruto

I am planning to read *Boruto: Naruto Next Generations* but I heard that the movie is canon. I also heard that the first few chapters of the manga cover the movie.

So what is the difference?

Comment: I think it's a couple of years after the movie, the rest of the manga at least. Or something along that line. I'm pretty sure it's sometime after the movie. The beginning, like you said, does cover what the movie is about. There's just some small changes.

Answer (score 3):

From watching the movie and reading the manga, as it stands, there are only a few differences.

The natural difference is simply pacing. The movie stretches the content out a bit, but the manga covers a near identical story over the course of 9 chapters, at 40-45 pages each. This is normal.

As for major differences, there is only 1 major difference I found, and it's inconsequential to the story as a whole if you limit the scope to just the 9 chapters and the movie. The manga is set to continue however, I believe anyway, and if it does, it might in the future build off any of its changes. But in terms of the 9 chapters vs the movie, outside of that one difference, the rest are minor and likely will not affect the story in the future.

As for what that difference is, for those who have not watched/read both:

> It's the form Momoshiki takes on after he consumes his guardian Kinshiki. In the movie, he takes on a red skinned demon look with pointy chin and a larger overall body. In the manga, his body changes very little, he gets covered in black markings. His 5 eyes (2 normal, 1 forehead, 2 on his hands), 3 of which are Rinnegan, are depicted as yellow. Because of this, the fight plays out differently, but overall, many of the same moves are used, and the end result is virtually identical.

That being said, if you can, watching the movie and reading the series can be entertaining, but if you limit yourself to only one of the two, the manga is the better one, since it's probably going to keep going, giving you more story to read. It's also the safer option to read the manga anyway, since those minor differences indeed might affect future story, but if you watched the movie instead, you would have missed them.

Answer (score 0):

In the series "boruto:naruto next generation" is the full series or anime or manga  but the movie boruto:Naruto the movie" is part of "Boruto:Naruto next generation" is also 
that episode and scene that are not in "Boruto:Naruto next generation" filmed but discussed e.g in "Boruto:Noruto the movie", the movie is avout on boruto cheating and using a ninja tool in chunin exam which is forbidden all these are also in "Boruto:Naruto next generation" but in this (borotu:Naruto the movie) .they discussed in detail