# Are there any significant differences between Boruto the movie and the corresponding arc in the anime?

Tags: boruto

The recent arc of *Boruto: Naruto Next Generations* seems to completely cover the plot of that movie.

Are there any differences (in terms of the story, animation, fight sequences, and drawing style) between that arc in the movie and the one in the series?

Comment: [Related](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/38821/what-is-the-difference-between-boruto-naruto-next-generation-manga-and-borut?rq=1). The question is about differences between the manga and the movie, but should be fairly similar

Comment: As adaptations tend to deviate from its source, especially concerning animes, I don't think that question is related to mine since it asks about the differences between the movie and the manga, not the anime. And deriving from that it also won't answer any differences in the animation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several differences. Especially the character design of transformed **Momoshiki Otsutsuki**. Kishimoto's design was used in the movie, and Ikemoto's design was used for the series.

As far as fighting Momoshiki, which had several difference between the movie and anime, The Chuunin Exam's final fight from anime also differs from the movie. Some fights were a bit more expanded like **Chou Chou**'s fight with **Shinki**.

Some of Boruto's fight scenes are also different from the movie, and most of the scenes from the anime left something more for the people to talk about, especially between **Shikadai** and **Boruto**, which is not shown from the movie.

A new Otsutsuki member was also shown in that arc, **Urashiki Ōtsutsuki**. The fish hook guy, this one did not appear in the movie.

**Mitsuki**'s abilities were not shown too much in the movie as much as the anime did, and **Katasuke**'s part is also slightly different in the anime.

Comment: I've heard that the fight btw. Naruto/Sasuke and Momoshiki has been improved in the series. It seems that it's more intense and detailed. Is that true?

Comment: @Eti2d1 yes, it was a bit improved than the movie version. they added some nostalgic elements in the anime version.